# Ожидание ответа от пользователя в Telegram Bot api php

Tags: php, telegram-bot, telegram

Как сформировать сообщение с вопросом к пользователю, записать ответ (с эти все понятно) и отобразить сообщение об успешном действии. Задача - попросить у пользователя адрес, после чего отобразить сообщение с просьбой ввести номер телефона и тд. Не совсем понятно как именно редиректить на нужный блок после ввода инфы.

Пробовал так сформировать сообщение чтобы затем считать колбек и отобразить нужный блок. Но так видимо нельзя, так как в данных приходящих на вебхук не отображается callback_data.

```
$message = ['chat_id'=>$chat_id,
    'message_id'=>$message_id,
    'text'=> 'Your Name :',
    'parse_mode'=>'html',
    'callback_data' => '3',
    'reply_markup' => json_encode(['selective' => false, 'callback_data' => '3'])];
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно где нибудь хранить информацию об ожидаемом вводе пользователя у себя на сервере. Я советую использовать поле в базе данных с привязкой к id пользователя телеграм. Таким образом вам нужно будет организовать такую последовательность действий:

1. Пользователь нажимает на кнопку, или выполняет любое другое действие после которого ему нужно будет указать Email
2. В базу данных сохраняете информацию о вводе пользователя (например `input = email`).
3. При следующем сообщении пользователя проверяете данные в поле `input` и вызываете соответствующий этому обработчик

Comment: можно поподробнее о 3-м пункте?

Comment: При отправке сообщения пользователем, на ваш сервер будет отправлен update с типом message. Проверяя поле input в базе данных (input == email), мы знаем, что в этом сообщении пользователь должен отправить email. Проводим валидацию текста сообщения и если удалось подтвердить что это email, сохраняем email куда вам нужно и ставим поле задаем значение input = null, таким образом заблокировав последующий ввод пользователю.